# Legal and Policy Implications of Integrating a Custom YouTube Experience in an Educational App for Children

Tags: youtube, google-play, google-play-services, policy

I'm currently developing an educational application for children and am contemplating the inclusion of a feature that would provide a customized YouTube experience. This feature aims to direct young users to educational content at specific times and restrict access to certain channels that might not be suitable for their age.

The functionality would be similar to a YouTube extension for browsers like Chrome, allowing for a personalized viewing experience. Importantly, this feature would not interfere with YouTube's monetization mechanisms - no ad blockers are involved, and all forms of monetization, including advertisements, would function as usual.

I'm reaching out to the community for insights:

Legal Considerations: Are there any legal issues with integrating such a feature into my app? Has anyone here undertaken a similar project, and what legal hurdles did you face?

Policy Compliance: How can I ensure compliance with YouTube's policies and terms of service while implementing this feature? Are there examples of similar extensions or apps that have successfully navigated these waters?

Precedent: Has anyone in this community done something similar before? If so, could you share your experiences and how you approached both the technical and legal aspects?

The goal is to maintain complete compliance with YouTube's terms while creating a safe, educational online environment for children. Any experiences, insights, or advice you could share would be immensely helpful.

Thank you in advance for your guidance!

I have created the app, however, I'm uncertain if this feature aligns with the Play Store's policies. While the app is designed with good intentions – to provide a safe and educational environment for children.